# Remove duplicate objects from JSON file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

This is the current JSON file:

```
[{
    "name": "Peter",
    "age": 30,
    "hair color": "brown"
}, {
    "name": "Steve",
    "age": 55,
    "hair color": "blonde"
}, {
    "name": "Steve",
    "age": 55,
    "hair color": "blonde"
}]
```

I want to remove the duplicate Steve individual from the list. How can I make a new JSON that checks if the object's name matches and remove any duplicates in JavaScript?

Comment: Does the order matter?

Comment: So you only care about the `name`, and none of the other properties?

Comment: Order does not matter. And we only care if 'name' matches. If there are two of the same, just have one remaining.

Comment: @user2836857 And what if other details in the objects are different? Which one to keep?

Comment: Good question. I am assuming they are all exact but you bring a good point up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must load the JSON data in to the program and parse that with [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), like this

```
var array = JSON.parse(content.toString())
```

To filter out the repeated names from the array of Objects, we use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function. You can store the names in an object, and next time when the same name appears we simply filter it out from the result.

```
var seenNames = {};

array = array.filter(function(currentObject) {
    if (currentObject.name in seenNames) {
        return false;
    } else {
        seenNames[currentObject.name] = true;
        return true;
    }
});

console.log(array);
# [ { name: 'Peter', age: 30, 'hair color': 'brown' },
#   { name: 'Steve', age: 55, 'hair color': 'blonde' } ]
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
var data = [{
    "name": "Peter",
    "age": 30,
    "hair color": "brown"
}, {
    "name": "Steve",
    "age": 55,
    "hair color": "blonde"
}, {
    "name": "Steve",
    "age": 55,
    "hair color": "blonde"
}]
 data = this.data.filter((obj, pos, arr) => {
            return arr.map(mapObj =>
                  mapObj.name).indexOf(obj.name) == pos;
            });
          console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) and the [`uniq`](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq) function:

```
_.uniq(array, false, function (item) { return item.name; })
```

Comment: No downvote but I don't think OP mentioned anything about underscore.

Comment: @thefourtheye I'm well aware. The answer isn't wrong, it just suggests  using a JS tool.

Comment: It's irrelevant if OP doesn't want to include a whole library just for this one task. You should make that determination first.

Comment: @cookiemonster I just am not a fan of reinventing the wheel every time a simple problem presents itself. Yes, the code I gave suggests using a library, and certainly people often do not want to add another library to the mix. However, it is extremely **declarative** code. thefourtheye's answer, for example, is not nearly as concise and immediately understandable. To each his own I guess.

Comment: @TimothyShields Even I like using `underscore` :)

Answer (score 1):

Loop, check, splice, repeat:

```
var distinctValues = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (distinctValues.hasOwnProperty(data[i].name]) {
        //already has it
        data.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
    } else {
        distinctValues[data[i].name] = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to decrement `i` when doing a `.splice()`, or iterate in reverse.

Comment: @cookiemonster -- Damnit, I always forget that... :\

Answer (score 0):

This was the best solution I could find that makes you able to filter on multiple values in you json object. Solution without _ (module)

```
array.filter((thing, index, self) =>
    index === self.findIndex((t) => (
    t.place === thing.place && t.name === thing.name // you can add more arguments here to filter more
  ))
)

//Other example
array.filter((thing, index, self) =>
    index === self.findIndex((t) => (
    t.place === thing.place && t.name === thing.name && t.time === thing.time
  ))
)
```

Answer (score -3):

Python one-liner from CLI:

`cat file_with_duplicates.json | python2 -c 'import sys; import json; sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(reduce(lambda x, y: x + [y] if y not in x else x, json.loads(sys.stdin.read()), [])))' > unique_items.txt`