# Map and Reduce JSON Objects with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

Consider this JSON object below:

```
{
   "cells":[
      {
         "count":"1",
         "gdp_growth__avg":1.90575802503285,
         "geo__name":"united states of america",
         "time":1990
      },
      {
         "count":"1",
         "gdp_growth__avg":9.17893670154459,
         "geo__name":"china",
         "time":1991
      },
      {
         "count":"1",
         "gdp_growth__avg":-5.04693945214571,
         "geo__name":"russia",
         "time":1991
      },
      {
         "count":"1",
         "gdp_growth__avg":-0.0622142217811472,
         "geo__name":"botswana",
         "time":1991
      },
      {
         "count":"1",
         "gdp_growth__avg":14.2407063986337,
         "geo__name":"china",
         "time":1992
      },
      {
         "count":"1",
         "gdp_growth__avg":-14.5310737731921,
         "geo__name":"russia",
         "time":1992
      },
      {
         "count":"1",
         "gdp_growth__avg":3.55494453739944,
         "geo__name":"united states of america",
         "time":1992
      },
      {
         "count":"1",
         "gdp_growth__avg":13.9643147001603,
         "geo__name":"china",
         "time":1993
      },
      {
         "count":"1",
         "gdp_growth__avg":-8.66854034194856,
         "geo__name":"botswana",
         "time":1993
      },
      {
         "count":"1",
         "gdp_growth__avg":2.74204850437989,
         "geo__name":"united states of america",
         "time":1993
      },
      {
         "count":"1",
         "gdp_growth__avg":4.04272516401846,
         "geo__name":"united states of america",
         "time":1994
      },
      {
         "count":"1",
         "gdp_growth__avg":13.0806818010789,
         "geo__name":"china",
         "time":1994
      },
      {
         "count":"1",
         "gdp_growth__avg":-12.5697559787493,
         "geo__name":"russia",
         "time":1994
      },
      {
         "count":"1",
         "gdp_growth__avg":10.9249803004994,
         "geo__name":"china",
         "time":1995
      },
      {
         "count":"1",
         "gdp_growth__avg":-4.14352840666389,
         "geo__name":"russia",
         "time":1995
      },
      {
         "count":"1",
         "gdp_growth__avg":2.71655384149574,
         "geo__name":"united states of america",
         "time":1995
      },
      {
         "count":"1",
         "gdp_growth__avg":10.0085233990531,
         "geo__name":"china",
         "time":1996
      },
      {
         "count":"1",
         "gdp_growth__avg":3.79848988541973,
         "geo__name":"united states of america",
         "time":1996
      }
]
}
```

I would to Map and Reduce and generate a new object containing a summation of the GDP growth for all the countries in the above JSON that might look roughly like this:

```
{  
  {
     "gdp_growth__avg":46.23,
     "geo__name":"united states of america",
  },
  {
     "gdp_growth__avg":16.23,
     "geo__name":"china",
  },
  {
     "gdp_growth__avg":36.23,
     "geo__name":"russia",
  },
  {
     "gdp_growth__avg":26.23, 
     "geo__name":"botswana",
     "time":1991
  }
 }
```

I have looked at [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and am not sure how best to proceed.

I was thinking something like this might be moving in the right directions, but does not seem to do what I was expecting:

```
      var arr = [{x:1},{x:2},{x:4}];

      arr.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return {x: a.x + b.x};
      });

      console.log(arr); //Outputs that same initial array
```

While I recognize that it is probably better and easier to do this on the server-side, I am wondering if what I am trying to do can be done on the client side with JavaScript. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want `console.log(arr.reduce(…))`. `reduce` does not alter the array (or even reassign the variable), it just *returns* a value.

Comment: @Bergi, +1 because i learned something here that i did not expect.  Thank you.

Comment: `map` and `reduce` can be used server side too if you use node.  Probably whatever your server can run can do it.  Most convenient in js or python (are there python-based servers?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
var data = { cells:[...] };

var r = data.cells.reduce(function(pv, cv) {
    if ( pv[cv.geo__name] ) {
        pv[cv.geo__name] += cv.gdp_growth__avg;
    } else {
        pv[cv.geo__name] = cv.gdp_growth__avg;
    }
    return pv;
}, {});

console.log(r);
```

Output example:

```
    { 
      'united states of america': 18.76051995774611,
      'china': 71.39814330096999,
      'russia': -36.291297610751,
      'botswana': -8.730754563729707 
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

The `Array.reduce` method doesn't change the array object, it returns the results in a new array.

Comment: No, it does not return a new array.

Comment: it depends on the type of accumulator we use, it can be json object or even a js Map ,but  array.map() returns a new array

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
var data = {"cells": [...]};

data.cells.map(function(datum) {
  return {
    geo__name: datum.geo__name,
    gdp_growth__avg: data.cells.filter(function(o) {
      return o.geo__name === datum.geo__name;
    }).reduce(function(sum, o) {
      return sum + o.gdp_growth__avg;
    }, 0)
  };
})
```

Needless to say, you can extract other properties from `datum` as well, such as `time`. I haven't.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do with better time complexity:

```js
let ans = [];
let map = new Map();
ques.cells.forEach(x => {
if(map[x.geo__name]){
map.set(x.geo__name, map[x.geo__name] + x.gdp_growth__avg);
}else{
map.set(x.geo__name,x.gdp_growth__avg);
}
});

map.forEach((v,k)=>{
ans.push({"geo__name":k, "gdp_growth__avg":v});
});
ques.cells = ans;
```

with solution looking like this:

```
[
  {
    "geo__name": "united states of america",
    "gdp_growth__avg": 3.79848988541973
  },
  {
    "geo__name": "china",
    "gdp_growth__avg": 10.0085233990531
  },
  {
    "geo__name": "russia",
    "gdp_growth__avg": -4.14352840666389
  },
  {
    "geo__name": "botswana",
    "gdp_growth__avg": -8.66854034194856
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

To the solution given by @Hunan, I added https://stackoverflow.com/a/53294268/341117 to get result without duplicates

The final solution I used is :

```
var data = {"cells": [...]};

data =  data.cells.map(function(datum) {
  return {
    geo__name: datum.geo__name,
    gdp_growth__avg: data.cells.filter(function(o) {
      return o.geo__name === datum.geo__name;
    }).reduce(function(sum, o) {
      return sum + o.gdp_growth__avg;
    }, 0)
  };
}).filter((obj, pos, arr) => {
        return arr.map(mapObj =>
              mapObj.geo__name).indexOf(obj.geo__name) == pos;
        });
```

JS Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/8b4z3yc5/